# JavaFX - painting a rgb array as an image

Tags: java, video, bufferedimage, javafx-2, vlcj

We are using [vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) to capture a webcam video and display it on the user screen. We capture it frame by frame, a 1280x720 image at around 30fps.

Our app UI is entirely JavaFX, and we are having problems displaying said frame.

Using Swing, we would do something like:

```
BufferedImage image; //create compatible image

public void onDisplay(int[] rgbBuffer){
      image.setRGB(0,0,width, height, rgbBuffer, 0, width);
      myJPane.repaint();  
}
```

But JavaFX's [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) class offers no such methods, and creating a `BufferedImage` just to convert it to a JavaFX `Image` (by using `Image.impl_fromPlatformImage()`) is highly costly.

**Question: How does one create a JavaFX `Image`, that can be set to an `ImageView`, based on a rgb `int[]`? Is there a better (as in "faster") way to display it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not yet part of the JavaFX platform - for now I believe you have to use the BufferedImage method you are currently using.

You can track the feature [Image Ops](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17409) request.  Anybody can sign up for a [jira account](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) and vote for the issue/add comments/detail use cases/etc or provide input to the design on the [JavaFX development mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).